# How can I tell if my Perl script is running under Windows?

Tags: windows, perl

What is the best way to programatically determine if a Perl script is executing on a Windows based system (Win9x, WinXP, Vista, Win7, etc.)?

Fill in the blanks here:

```
my $running_under_windows = ... ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> - `$OSNAME`
> - `$^O`
>
> The name of the operating system under which this copy of Perl was built, as determined during the configuration process. The value is identical to `$Config{'osname'}`. See also Config and the -V command-line switch documented in perlrun.
>
> In Windows platforms, `$^O` is not very helpful: since it is always `MSWin32`, it doesn't tell the difference between 95/98/ME/NT/2000/XP/CE/.NET. Use `Win32::GetOSName()` or `Win32::GetOSVersion()` (see [Win32](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32) and [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html)) to distinguish between the variants.

Comment: What about Cygwin?  $^O = 'cygwin'

Comment: @mobrule - If we're using Cygwin, does it matter? I don't have a Windows box to test it out on, but if you're using Cygwin you basically get the best of both words (for the most part) so it really shouldn't matter. If you want to know how Cygwin affects `$^O` you should run Perl under Cygwin and find out.

Comment: It depends on what the motivation is for identifying Windows. Maybe knorv is working around some limitation of Windows, or maybe he is taking advantage of some feature available only in Windows.

Comment: mobrule: $^O eq 'MSWin32' under Cygwin.

Comment: You don't have to think about the details because David Cantrell already did that for you in Devel::CheckOS.

Comment: `$^O eq 'darwin'` under Mac OS X

Comment: $OSNAME requires explicit package name? (git-bash in windows)

Comment: $^O yields "msys" in git-bash

Answer (score 6):

```
$^O eq 'MSWin32'
```

(Source: The `perlvar` manpage)

Answer (score 3):

Use [Devel::CheckOS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-CheckOS). It handles all of the logic and special cases for you. I usually do something like:

```
use Devel::CheckOS qw(die_unsupported os_is);

die "You need Windows to run this program!" unless os_is('MicrosoftWindows');
```

The 'MicrosoftWindows' families knows about things such as Cygwin, so if you are on Windows but not at the cmd prompt, `os_is()` will still give you the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is very quick and dirty, and wouldn't bet it's 100% portable, but still useful in a pinch.
Check for presence of back slashes in the PATH Env variable, since PATH is common to both Windows and Unix.
So - in Perl:

```
if ( $ENV{PATH}=~m{\\} ) {
  #Quick and dirty: It's windows!
  print "It's Windows!";
} else {
  print "It's Unix!";
}
```

Comment: Unless, of course, you're on cygwin.  Then your code mistakenly thinks it's running unix.