# Making Perl on Windows work like Linux (wildcarded param expansion)

Tags: windows, perl

It would be nice for Perl scripts on Windows to work like they do on Linux with regard to wildcard containing file names.

For example:

```
perl myscript.pl *.txt
```

On Linux, bash will expand the *.txt to a set of file names and pass those to the perl interpreter as individual parameters. On Windows, the *.txt gets passed directly into Perl.

So, basically, what I am looking for is something to put at the top of the script that will expand wildcard params, so that the rest of the script can be the same as on Linux.

For example:

**myscript.pl**

```
use warnings;
use strict;

# Mystery code to expand all wildcard params, fudging ARGV in the process
# ----
<Insert code here>
# ----

# Rest of script
...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Install [`Win32::Autoglob`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aAutoglob) if your Perl doesn't come with it.
2. Set the `PERL5OPT` environment variable to `-MWin32::Autoglob` or just `use Win32::Autoglob`.

Answer (score 4):

There's a big difference between the shells of the operating systems that makes this less obvious: in most Unix shells, [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) (wildcard expansion) is done by the shell, on Windows this is not the case.

This means that an application started by a Unix shell will see a long list of filenames in argv, whereas the same application started under Windows will get 1 pattern with the wildcards embedded.

Starting the script in bash via Cygwin is possibly the cleanest option.  You could also detect Windows ( [How can I tell if my Perl script is running under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423900/how-can-i-tell-if-my-perl-script-is-running-under-windows) ) and [glob in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html).

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer:

```
my @args = glob "@ARGV";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code snipet to expand the wildcard and get the file names:

```
my @list = <$ARGV[0]>;
```