# perl passing parameters on windows

Tags: windows, perl, parameters, quotes

I have the following code :

```
$op = shift or die "Usage: rename expr [files]\n";
chomp(@ARGV = <STDIN>) unless @ARGV;
print "$op";

for ( @ARGV )
{
  print "$_";
  $was = $_;
  eval $op;
  die $@ if $@;
  rename ( $was, $_ ) unless $was eq $_;
 }
```

It produces the expected result on a linux machine, i.e. when I run

```
  perl massrenamer.pl 's/\.txt/\.txtla/' *.txt
```

I get proper results. I try to execute the same thing on a windows machine, with strawberry perl installed like

```
  perl massrenamer.pl 's/\.txt/\.txtla/' *.txt
```

and

```
  perl massrenamer.pl "s/\.txt/\.txtla/" *.txt
```

and

```
  perl massrenamer.pl 's/\.txt/\.txtla/' "*.txt"
```

but I get no result. Could someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wilcard expansion is done by the shell, but not when the parameter is enclosed between quotes, on windows to port perl scripts there is a module Win32::AutoGlob [see also this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417991/making-perl-on-windows-work-like-linux-wildcarded-param-expansion)

A quick fix: replace ( @ARGV ) by ( glob "@ARGV" )

```
$op = shift or die "Usage: rename expr [files]\n";
chomp(@ARGV = <STDIN>) unless @ARGV;
print "$op";

for ( glob "@ARGV" )
{
  print "$_";
  $was = $_;
  eval $op;
  die $@ if $@;
  rename ( $was, $_ ) unless $was eq $_;
}
```